# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

User Experience—Stack Exchange's [2nd moderator election](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Benny Skogberg] [image: JohnGB]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6040666836566016/0).

Comment: Congrats gentlemen :)

Comment: @VitalyMijiritsky Thank you! :)

Comment: Congratulations! Your promotion is well-deserved.

Comment: @3nafish You gotta tell me how to pronounce your nickname :)

Comment: Congrats guys. And well done everyone for taking part, those putting themselves forward and those voting.

Comment: @Vitaly, It's pronounced three-na-fish (one better than tunafish)

Comment: @3nafish Oh! I hadn't picked up on that :).

Comment: Can someone explain me (or point me to a link) the voting system? Why are there different rounds?

Comment: @stefan.s: We use a [single transferable vote system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote). The rounds occur when votes are transferred either because a candidate is eliminated or elected. Often the results are identical to a straight vote, but when there are multiple candidates and positions STV systems work better in important edge cases.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks Jon, never heard of that. Looks a bit to complicated in the morning. I'll need some more coffee :-)

Comment: Congratulations to the UX community for making such good choices and thank you John and Benny for volunteering. Congratulations to you two as well.

Comment: Hoorah! Welcome to the moderation community folks!

Answer (score 9):

Congrats chaps! Welcome on board.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I'm honored to be part of a great team!

Answer (score 7):

## **Congratulations!**

You will make [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com) even more amazing than it already is.

*Good luck and happy moderating!*

Comment: Thank you Maverick! I'll do my very best :-)

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations boys.

I wish I could see at least one girl in the list of moderators. Looking forward to see females next time :)

Answer (score 4):

## UX.StackExchange is a fantastic place

due to the community, but also because the moderators do a great job. I have the utmost respect for the first group of moderators **BenBrocka, JonW and Rahul - thank you so much guys!**

Given how impressively active **Benny Skogberg and JohnGB** have been, I'm absolutely sure they'll do a great job too - **congratulations!**

Comment: Thank you for those kind words @greenforest! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, very well deserved :). Looking forward to the building of an ever more awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations Ben and John! Here's to hoping a bigger, better and thriving UX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations guys, looking forward for data and wearables year's new topics!

Answer (score 0):

So good, and Congratulation Ben and John. I hope you the bests and making Better Experience